# How can I select an element that is not a direct ancestor of my current element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

**HTML :**

```
<div class="group">
    <div class="link"><a class="add_link" href="javascript:">add</a></div>
    <p class="values">test....</p>
    <input type="text" class="box1" value="10" />
    <input type="text" class="box2" value="20" />
    <input type="text" class="box3" value="30" />
    <input type="text" class="final" value="100" />
</div>

<div class="group">
    <div class="link"><a class="add_link" href="javascript:">add</a></div>
    <p class="values">test....</p>
    <input type="text" class="box1" value="5" />
    <input type="text" class="box2" value="10" />
    <input type="text" class="box3" value="15" />
    <input type="text" class="final" value="700" />
</div>
<div class="group">
    <div class="link"><a class="add_link" href="javascript:">add</a></div>
    <p class="values">test....</p>
    <input type="text" class="box1" value="103" />
    <input type="text" class="box2" value="230" />
    <input type="text" class="box3" value="350" />
    <input type="text" class="final" value="770" />
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.add_link').click(function(){

    value=$(this).parent('div').next('p').next('input.box1').next('input.box2').next('input.box3').next('input.final').val();
    alert(value);

});
```

**jsFiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/Thn6A/

When I click the element with class **add_link**, I want to select its group's class **final** value. I had written the above code for it, and that seems to work, but I would like a more direct selector for targeting the element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways, but I would say this is the easiest:

```
$('.add_link').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); //Instead of href="javascript:"
    var value = $(this).closest(".group").find(".final").val();
    alert(value);
});
```

Also, you can use the `event` object to prevent the default action of the click, instead of adding it to your `href` attribute.

Read more: http://api.jquery.com/closest

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
$('.add_link').click(function(){
  var value=$(this).parent().siblings('.final').val();
    alert(value);          
});
```

***Working Demo:***
http://jsfiddle.net/saji89/Wcs7t/

A comparison of the different methods:
http://jsperf.com/closest-find-vs-parent-siblings

Found the fastest method to be:
`var value=$(this).parent().find('.final').val();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.add_link').click(function(){
        value=$(this).parent('div').siblings('input.final').val();
        alert(value);    
});
```

Comment: -1 have you tested this? add_link doesn't have any input sibling :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `last-child` to get last value of any tag.

Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/2u4SM/